# Multiple Vms Arm template with different Vm names,sizes and same custom

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I have seen many templates to create multi vms as loop using copy function. Ex: vm1, vm2 etc. But this is not how we put in practice as each vm has different function and the naming convention doesn't help.
I am trying to create a template with different vM names, sizes and a single custom Image.
Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using parameters, we can differentiate the VM names, sizes etc:

```
"parameters": {
    "org": {
    "type": "array",
    "defaultValue": [
        "contoso",
        "fabrikam",
        "coho"
        ]
    }
},
```

<![endif]-->

As Copy functions can get the correct value from parameter array and can set the count with length() automatically.

Refer to [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/copy-resources#copy-limits) to understand more.

Also have a look on this [answer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/2943/arm-template-to-create-multiple-vms-having-differe.html), thanks to SamaraSoucy for explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using an array of name/value pairs, either in the parameters or variables section of your template, for example,

```
"parameters": {
    "vms": {
        "type": "array",
        "defaultValue": [
            {
                "name": "vm1",
                "size": "Standard_DS1_v2"
            },
            {
                "name": "vm2",
                "size": "Standard_A1_v2"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Then you can dereference the array with

```
"copy": {
    "name": "vmCopy",
    "count": "[length(parameters('vms'))]"    
}
```

and

```
parameters('vms')[copyIndex()].name
parameters('vms')[copyIndex()].size
```